# Deterministic and nondeterministic finite automata in scheme

Tags: scheme, state-machine

This is the implementation of both Deterministic Finite Automata (DFAs) and
Nondeterministic Finite Automata (NFAs) on r7rs scheme, using only
SRFI 1.

The file automata.scm contains the implementation of the procedures
to make a DFA (make-dfa), make a NFA (make-nfa) and run either one on
a string (automaton-run).

The file exempla.scm contains examples of DFAs and NFAs implemented
using the procedures of the other file.   This is an executable file;
when run, it computes those automata on a set of predefined strings.

automata.scm:

```lisp
(import (srfi 1))               ; for fold, any, filter, etc

; srfi 1 should have a flatmap...
(define (flatmap proc seq)
  (fold-right append '() (map proc seq)))

; selectors
(define (automaton-type automaton) (car automaton))
(define (initstate automaton) (cadr automaton))
(define (isfinal automaton) (caddr automaton))
(define (nextstate automaton) (cadddr automaton))
(define (nextstates automaton) (cadddr automaton))

; A Deterministic Finite Automaton (DFA) is constructed from three
; elements:
; - An initial state.
; - A procedure that determines whether a given state is a final state.
; - A procedure that, given a state and a symbol, gets the next state.
(define (make-dfa initstate isfinal nextstate)
  (list 'dfa initstate isfinal nextstate))

; A Nondeterministic Finite Automaton (NFA) is just like a DFA, but the
; third element (nextstates) returns a list of next states given a state
; and either a symbol or nil.
(define (make-nfa initstate isfinal nextstates)
  (list 'nfa initstate isfinal nextstates))

; run automaton
(define (automaton-run automaton string)

  (define (dfa-run automaton string)
    ((isfinal automaton)
     (fold (nextstate automaton) (initstate automaton) (string->list string))))

  (define (nfa-step symbol states)
    (filter
      (lambda (x) x)
      (flatmap
        (lambda (state) ((nextstates automaton) symbol state))
        states)))

  (define (nfa-run automaton string)
    (any
      (isfinal automaton)
      (fold
        (lambda (symbol states)
          (let ((states (lset-union eq? states (nfa-step '() states))))
            (nfa-step symbol states)))
        (list (initstate automaton))
        (string->list string))))

  (cond ((eq? (automaton-type automaton) 'dfa) (dfa-run automaton string))
        ((eq? (automaton-type automaton) 'nfa) (nfa-run automaton string))))
```

exempla.scm:

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/env scheme-r7rs
(import (scheme small))
(load "automata.scm")

; Let's define some strings.
; Our alphabet are the numbers 0 and 1.
(define strings
  (list
    "01010"
    "11010"
    "10111"
    "00000"
    "0000"))

; This DFA recognizes the language of strings beginning with 1 and
; ending with 0.  All our states are symbols like 'qx.
(define start-1-end-0
  (make-dfa
    'qs
    (lambda (state) (eq? state 'q0))
    (lambda (symbol state)
      (cond ((and (eq? state 'qs) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'qe)
            ((and (eq? state 'qs) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q1)
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q0)
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q1)
            ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q0)
            ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q1)
            ((and (eq? state 'qe) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'qe)
            ((and (eq? state 'qe) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'qe)
            (else #f)))))

; This DFA recognizes the language of string with at least three 1's
(define has-three-1s
  (make-dfa
    'q0
    (lambda (state) (eq? state 'q3))
    (lambda (symbol state)
      (cond ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q0)
            ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q1)
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q1)
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q2)
            ((and (eq? state 'q2) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q2)
            ((and (eq? state 'q2) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q3)
            ((and (eq? state 'q3) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q3)
            ((and (eq? state 'q3) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q3)
            (else #f)))))

; This DFA recognizes the language of strings which does not have the
; substring "110" in it.
(define has-no-110
  (make-dfa
    'q0
    (lambda (state)
      (or (eq? state 'q0)
          (eq? state 'q1)
          (eq? state 'q2)))
    (lambda (symbol state)
      (cond ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q0)
            ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q1)
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q0)
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q2)
            ((and (eq? state 'q2) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q3)
            ((and (eq? state 'q2) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q2)
            ((and (eq? state 'q3) (eq? symbol #\0)) 'q3)
            ((and (eq? state 'q3) (eq? symbol #\1)) 'q3)
            (else #f)))))

; This NFA recognizes the language of strings whose third-to-last symbol is 1
(define third-to-last-is-1
  (make-nfa
    'q0
    (lambda (state) (eq? state 'q3))
    (lambda (symbol state)
      (cond ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q0))
            ((and (eq? state 'q0) (eq? symbol #\1)) (list 'q0 'q1))
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q2))
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\1)) (list 'q2))
            ((and (eq? state 'q2) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q3))
            ((and (eq? state 'q2) (eq? symbol #\1)) (list 'q3))
            (else #f)))))

; This NFA recognizes the language of strings of k zeroes, where k is a
; multiple of 2 or 3
(define k-zeroes
  (make-nfa
    'q0
    (lambda (state) (or (eq? state 'q1) (eq? state 'q3)))
    (lambda (symbol state)
      (cond ((and (eq? state 'q0) (null? symbol)) (list 'q1 'q3))
            ((and (eq? state 'q1) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q2))
            ((and (eq? state 'q2) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q1))
            ((and (eq? state 'q3) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q4))
            ((and (eq? state 'q4) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q5))
            ((and (eq? state 'q5) (eq? symbol #\0)) (list 'q3))
            (else #f)))))

; a test function
(define (test dfa-name dfa)
  (define (iter rest)
    (if (null? rest)
        (newline)
        (begin
          (display dfa-name)
          (display " on ")
          (display (car rest))
          (display ":\t")
          (display (if (automaton-run dfa (car rest)) "accept" "reject"))
          (newline)
          (iter (cdr rest)))))
  (iter strings))

(define (main args)
  (test "start-1-end-0" start-1-end-0)
  (test "has-three-1s" has-three-1s)
  (test "has-no-110" has-no-110)
  (test "third-to-last-is-1" third-to-last-is-1)
  (test "k-zeroes" k-zeroes)

  (exit #t))
```

Comment: Code on github: https://github.com/phillbush/automata.scm

Comment: I updated the code on github to use SRFI 113 with set operations. I was using SRFI 1's lset-union which, as I was told on #scheme at Libera.chat, is sub-optimal.